# Can I use a class variable in a Scala match statement?

Tags: class, scala

Say I have something like this:

```
obj match {
    case objTypeOne : TypeOne => Some(objTypeOne)
    case objTypeTwo : TypeTwo => Some(objTypeTwo)
    case _ => None
}
```

Now I want to generalise, to pass in one of the types to match:

```
obj match {
    case objTypeOne : clazz => Some(objTypeOne)
    case objTypeTwo : TypeTwo => Some(objTypeTwo)
    case _ => None
}
```

But this isn't allowed, I think for syntactic rather than semantic reasons (although I guess also that even though the clazz is a Class[C] the type is erased and so the type of the Option will be lost).

I ended up with:

```
if(clazzOne.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass)) Some(clazz.cast(obj))
if(obj.isInstanceOf[TypeTwo]) Some(obj.asInstanceOf[TypeTwo])
None
```

I just wondered if there was a nicer way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use pattern guards to achieve that. Try something like this:

```
obj match {
    case objTypeTwo : TypeTwo => Some(objTypeTwo)
    case objTypeOne if clazz.isAssignableFrom(objTypeOne.getClass) => Some(clazz.cast(objTypeOne))
    case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You could define an extractor to match your object:

```
class IsClass[T: Manifest] {
  def unapply(any: Any): Option[T] = {
    if (implicitly[Manifest[T]].erasure.isInstance(any)) {
       Some(any.asInstanceOf[T])
    } else {
       None
    }
  }
}
```

So let's test it:

```
class Base { def baseMethod = () }
class Derived extends Base

val IsBase = new IsClass[Base]

def test(a:Any) = a match {
    case IsBase(b) => 
      println("base")
      b.baseMethod
    case _ => println("?")
  }

test(new Base)
test(1)
```

You will have to define a val for your extractor, you can't inline `IsBase`, for example. Otherwise it would be interpreted as an extractor.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can use a local type alias for that:</strike>

```
def matcher[T](obj: Any)(implicit man: Manifest[T]) = {
   val instance = man.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
   type T = instance.type // type alias
   obj match { 
      case objTypeOne : T => "a"
      case objTypeTwo : TypeTwo => "b"
      case _ => "c"
   }
}

scala> matcher[TypeOne](TypeOne())
res108: java.lang.String = a

scala> matcher[TypeTwo](TypeOne())
res109: java.lang.String = c
```

**UPDATE:** Aaron Novstrup has pointed out that singleton type will only work if `man.erasure.newInstance==obj` (see §3.2.1 of the spec)

Comment: This looks great, but I can't work out how to pass the type alias in as a parameter. I'm trying to find something of a certain Class, passing in the Class (currently a Class[C]) and I have different methods that look for different classes.

Comment: I don't think this is what @Dan intended.  In order for `obj2` to be of type `obj1.type`, it must be equal to `obj1`.

Comment: No. `obj1` is just an instance of the same type as `obj2` - objects shouldn't be equal.

Comment: @Vasil 1) This code assumes that T has a no-arg constructor. 2) It doesn't compile in the Scala 2.8.0 REPL. 3) It won't work if `obj != man.erasure.newInstance`.

Comment: @Aaron 1) Agreed. 2) Thx. Fixed now. 3) Can you give an example? I'm not sure I get your point. In the snippet abouve `obj != man.erasure.newInstance` aren't equal, and they shouldn't.

Comment: Well, assuming `TypeOne` is a case class, they _are_ equal.  Try `class A; val res = matcher[A](new A)`.

Comment: The reason is found in §3.2.1 of the spec: "A singleton type [...] p.type [...] denotes the set of values consisting of null and the value denoted by p".

Comment: Reading the spec ATM. Thanx for opening my eyes on singleton types! - I've misgot the concept.